# How to use js and css in sub pages laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm on making a websites that uses Laravel 5.5 and blade templating engine for the view.

It's working on most of the browsers both desktop and mobile. But when I do a testing on an old Android mobile, I am getting error. I have checked anywhere on Google but could't find any answer.

It seems that the blade view that extends this layout, cannot read the function from the template layout. It shows the error "function undefined", and even for variable that I declared on the layout template, all unreadable on the view that extends this layout, even js file.

layout.blade.php:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var main_url = "https://test.com";

function checkout(){
alert(0);
}
</script>

@yield('scripts')
```

page.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonClick(){
checkout();
}
</script>
@endsection
```

main.js:

```
alert(main_url);
```

So, there's only one problem here, seems like the scripts that I have declared on the layout, are not rendered or something if we open it from old Android mobile browser.

The checkout function that I call on the `buttonClick` inside the `page.blade.php` is showing error undefined, and also the  `alert(main_url)` that I call on the `main.js` file is shown undefined too.

Is there any suggestion for my problems?

Comment: is this error for a specific browser (old android one) only??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes, desktop any browser, ios phone, new android os all fine. I just check on this old android is Android 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@yield` is for load content, So you should use `stack` and `push` for load **js** and **css**.

**layout.blade.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var main_url = "https://test.com";

function checkout(){
alert(0);
}
</script>

@stack('scripts')
```

**page.blade.php:**

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonClick(){
checkout();
}
</script>
@endpush
```

Check more info [push stack](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks)

Comment: It works! thank you very much! I was try stack and push before, but i think i was wrong typing, and now it works! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you:

page.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('scripts')
@push
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonClick(){
   checkout();
}
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: i tried to change the section into push, and yield on the layout into stack, and it shown and error "function undefined".

Comment: I also tried to add @parent after the section("scripts") and its also shown the same error :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that might be chance to have some browser issue

Comment: I think the issue is about to order. Can you import your main.js after the script tag into layout.blade.php?

Comment: I think i wrongly type the stack push, thats why not working, it works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's how javascript (and others too) works. Browser reads code from **top** to **bottom**.

Since you placed `<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>` before `var main_url = "https://test.com";`, of course `main_url` in `js/main.js` is undefined.

You just need to aware with orders.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var main_url = "https://test.com";

function checkout(){
alert(0);
}
</script>

<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

About `buttonClick` shows undefined, we don't have a clue, since you don't post your code, where you call it.

Comment: yes, I already put the js on below, and now it works, thank you very much